# Navigation Bars in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm working on creating a team website at work. I would like to make a nav greyed out such that when I click it, nothing happens. It seems that the default nav options always link to an empty page.

Any assistance is much appreciated. I am using sharepoint online for site creation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using IE F12 developer tools to check if some JavaScript error occurs or not.

And provide some screenshots for further research.

If you want to customize navigation bar, the articles below for your reference:

https://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/2014/03/31/customizing-sharepoint-2013-global-navigation-with-css-and-jquery-part-5/

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/11/sharepoint-2013-top-navigation-bar-branding-css.html

https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/branding-top-navigation-in-sharepoint-2013